# Visual studio in Administrator mode

Tags: visual-studio-2012

my visual studio is not opening in administrator mode on opening a project by clicking a solution. By default i set it as run as administrator. but, still it is not opening if i directly open the project by clicking the project solution file.

Comment: Please ask to your network team. Else restart it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open Visual Studio, right-click on the Taskbar icon of it, and select Properties.

In the tab Shortcut, press the Advanced button and tick 'Run as administrator'. Click OK.
In the tab Compatibility, tick the 'Run this program as an administrator' option. Click OK.

Apply and close the properties dialog.

I changed those settings on my computer and it always starts in administrator mode.

Comment: This does not work in most cases. Opening a .sln file will launch VS in non-admin mode

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy of [my answer to a similar post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/462912/always-start-visual-studio-as-an-administrator-on-windows-8/512928#512928):

### Option 1 - Set VSLauncher.exe and DevEnv.exe to always run as admin

To have Visual Studio always run as admin **when opening any .sln file**:

1. Navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe`.
2. Right-click on `VSLauncher.exe` and choose **Troubleshoot compatibility**.
3. Choose **Troubleshoot program**.
4. Check off **The program requires additional permissions** and hit Next.
5. Click the **Test the program...** button to launch VS.
6. Click Next, then hit **Yes, save these settings for this program**, and then the **close** buton.

To have Visual Studio always run as an admin **when just opening visual studio directly**, do the same thing to the DevEnv.exe file(s).  These file are located at:

#### Visual Studio 2010

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

#### Visual Studio 2012

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

#### Visual Studio 2013

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

#### Visual Studio 2015

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

### Option 2 - Use VSCommands extension for Visual Studio

Install the free [VSCommands extension for Visual Studio](https://superuser.com/questions/462912/always-start-visual-studio-as-an-administrator-on-windows-8/512928#512928) (it's in [the Visual Studio Extensions Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=VSCommands&f%5B0%5D.Value=VSCommands&f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&ac=4)) and then configure it to always have Visual Studio start with admin privileges by going to Tools -> VSCommands -> Options -> IDE Enhancements -> General and check off `Always start Visual Studio with elevated permissions` and click the Save button.

**Note:** VSCommands is not currently available for VS 2015, but their site says they are working on updating it to support VS 2015.

### My Opinion

I prefer Option 2 because:

- it also allows you to easily turn off this functionality.
- VSCommands comes with lots of other great features so I always have it installed anyways.
- it's just easier to do than option 1.